# How to use p.locateCenterOnScreen to find 2 images at once?

Tags: python

So I have some code that runs in a loop trying to find Microsoft Edge. Once it's found, it will break the loop and continue with the rest of the program. Here is the code:

```
#! /usr/bin/env python
import pyautogui as p
import time
import random
from hashlib import sha256

def search(query):
    p.hotkey("ctrl","e")
    time.sleep(.1)
    p.write(query)
    p.press("enter")
    time.sleep(.67)

def imageFind(image,g,double):
    a = 0
    b = 0
    while(a==0 and b==0):
        try:
            a,b = p.locateCenterOnScreen(image,grayscale=g)
        except TypeError:
            pass

    if double == True:
        time.sleep(1)
        p.doubleClick(a,b)
    else:
        p.click(a,b)

    return a,b

#p.hotkey("win","d")
counter = 1
while counter == 1:
    image_find = imageFind("Edge.png",False,False)
    if all(image_find):
        counter = 0
p.write(["win"])
time.sleep(1)
p.write("notepad")
time.sleep(1)
p.write(["enter"])
time.sleep(1)
p.write("Found Edge")
```

How can I do this for two images at the same time? For example, I have tried:

```
counter = 1
while counter == 1:
    image_find = imageFind("Edge.png",False,False)
    image_find2 = imageFind("Firefox.png",False,False)
    if all(image_find):
        counter = 0
        p.write(["win"])
        time.sleep(1)
        p.write("notepad")
        time.sleep(1)
        p.write(["enter"])
        time.sleep(1)
        p.write("Found Edge")
    elif all(image_find2):
        counter = 0
        p.write(["win"])
        time.sleep(1)
        p.write("notepad")
        time.sleep(1)
        p.write(["enter"])
        time.sleep(1)
        p.write("Found Firefox")
```

But it seems to stay on `image_find = imageFind("Edge.png",False,False)` until it finds Edge.png before moving on to the next line below it for Firefox.png, which means Edge always has to be found first.

How can I structure this so that python is looking for both at the same time and will follow the condition for which ever is found first?

Thank you!

NOTE: I've just realised I don't even need the while loop as again it won't continue to the next line of code anyway unless the image is found.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Refined code to achieve this:

```
counter = 1
while counter == 1:
    Img_1 = p.locateCenterOnScreen(“img_1.png”)
    if img_1 is not None:
        counter = 0
    Img_2 = p.locateOnCenterScreen(“img_2.png”)
    if img_2 is not None:
    counter = 0
```

Remove:

```
def imageFind(image,g,double):
    a = 0
    b = 0
    while(a==0 and b==0):
        try:
            a,b = p.locateCenterOnScreen(image,grayscale=g)
        except TypeError:
            pass
```